# Parse JSON containing an array of enums in Kotlin with Klaxon

Tags: json, kotlin, klaxon

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to parse an array of enums from JSON:

```
val convertColor = object: Converter<Color> {
    override fun toJson(value: Color): String? = when(value) {
        Color.R -> "red"
        Color.G -> "green"
        Color.B -> "blue"
        else -> null
    }

    override fun fromJson(jv: JsonValue): Color = when(jv.inside) {
        "red" -> Color.R
        "green" -> Color.G
        "blue" -> Color.B
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Color")
    }
}

enum class Color { R, G, B }
data class Root (val colors: Array<Color>)
```

Then I try to parse a sample with:

```
val klaxon = Klaxon().converter(convertColor)
val result = klaxon.parse<Root>("""
{
    "colors": ["red", "green", "blue"]
}
""")
```

But I get this runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch
```

It seems like the converter is not applied to the array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you replace `Array` with `List`, which is recommended anyway:

```
data class Root(val colors: List<Color>)
```